# Sacar informacion con php desde 2 tablas mysql. con LIMIT en la segunda

Tags: php, mysql

Intento con php sacar informaciones desde 2 tablas MYSQL , la primera tabla es un listado de usuarios. En la segunda es un listado de estados de cada usuario. Entonce necesito sacar por cada usuario su ultimo estado de la segunda tabla.
Me funciona bien el codigo , pero no consigo poner LIMIT 1 para la segunda tabla.

Gracias Un saludo

code:

```
SELECT  a.* , b.* FROM users a, fichaje b WHERE a.empresa ='empresa' and b.usuario=a.username ORDER BY a.nombre ASC , b.fecha DESC, b.hora DESC LIMIT 0, 1
```

EDIT:

Tabla users:

```
id - username -nombre - apelido
1  - usuario1 - 1     -  2
2  - usuario2 - u2    - u3
```

Tabla fichaje:

```
    id - usuario - fecha - hora - status
    1 - usuario1 - 23-07-2021 - 12:05:00 - Start
    2 - usuario1 - 23-07-2021 - 16:05:00 - Pausa
    3 - usuario1 - 23-07-2021 - 18:05:00 - Reanudar
    4 - usuario1 - 23-07-2021 - 22:05:00 - Stop 
    5 - usuario2 - 23-07-2021 - 12:05:00 - Start
   6 - usuario2 - 23-07-2021 - 16:05:00 - Pausa
    7 - usuario2 - 23-07-2021 - 18:05:00 - Reanudar
    8 - usuario2 - 23-07-2021 - 22:05:00 - Stop
```

Quero de la segunda tabla fichaje salga solo el ultimo Status.

Comment: Puedes agregar la relación de tu tabla y el resultado del ejemplo que comentas.

Comment: He modificado mi pregunta , espero que me entiende mejor ahora

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es obtener primeramente las fechas máximas que tienes por usuario, eso te permitirá saber cual es su ultimo estado. Sin embargo se atraviesa la problemática de que tienes en campos separados la fecha con la hora, por lo que se tiene que unir en un solo valor fecha-hora, en este caso podemos usuar la instrucción `STR_TO_DATE` y hacer un formato de fecha

```
STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(f.`fecha`, ' ', f.`hora`), '%Y-%c-%e %T')
```

Solucionado este detalle puedes hacer una consulta que te de la hora máxima por usuario

```
SELECT MAX(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(f.`fecha`, ' ', f.`hora`), '%Y-%c-%e %T')) AS FechaHora 
FROM `fichaje` f 
GROUP BY usuario
```

Teniendo lista esta consulta, la puedes incluir como subquery para filtrar de tu tabla original y hacer la unión con la tabla de usuarios, quedando la consulta completa como:

```
SELECT * FROM fichaje T0
INNER JOIN `users` T1 ON T1.`username` = T0.`usuario`
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(T0.`fecha`, ' ', T0.`hora`), '%Y-%c-%e %T') IN (
    SELECT MAX(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(f.`fecha`, ' ', f.`hora`), '%Y-%c-%e %T')) AS FechaHora 
    FROM `fichaje` f 
    GROUP BY usuario
)
```

Cabe mencionar el hecho del group by sin traer el campo de agrupación `usuario` funciona con MYSQL pero con otros motores no se si pueda presentar un problema.

Comment: Hola buenas. No es justo lo que necesito. Tengo que sacar el listado de usuarios de la tabla users, y a cada usuario sacar de la segunda tabla fichaje el ultimo status. No por fecha

Comment: Hola, ¿Como sabes cuál es el ultimo estatus de cada usuario si no es por fecha?